# Strange behavior in a simple for using uint

Tags: actionscript-3

This works as expected:

```
for (var i:uint = 5; i >= 1; i-- ) 
{   
    trace(i);  // output is from 5~1, as expected
}
```

---

This is the strange behavior:

```
for (var i:uint = 5; i >= 0; i-- ) 
{   
    trace(i)
}

// output:
5
4
3
2
1
0
4294967295
4294967294
4294967293
...
```

Below 0, something like a MAX_INT appears and it goes on decrementing forever. Why is this happening?

**EDIT**

I tested a similar code using C++, with a unsigned int and I have the same result. Probably the condition is being evaluated after the decrement.

Comment: Its not about conditions, its about datatypes, and uint is an unsigned data type.  So as you decrement i it reaches MAX_VALUE.

Comment: I do not know about the actionscript, but compliers for other languages may even warn you that a condition is always true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you are describing has little to do with any programming language.  This is true for C, C++, actionscript, etc.  Let me say this though, what you do see is quite normal behavior and has to do with the way a number is represented (see the wiki article and read about unsigned integers).

Because you are using an `uint` ([unsigned integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29)).  Which can only be a positive number, the type you are using cannot represent negative numbers so if you take a uint like this:

`uint i = 0;`

And you reduce 1 from the above

`i = i - 1;`

In this case `i` does not represent negative numbers, as it is unsigned.  Then `i` will display the maximum value of a `uint` data type.

Your edit that you posted above,

> "...in C++, .. same result..."

Should give you a clue as to why this is happening, it has nothing to do with what language you are using, or when the comparison is done.  It has to do with what data type you are using.

As an excercise, fire up that C++ program again and write a program that displays the maximum value of a `uint`.  The program should not display any defined constants :)..it should take you one line of code too!

Comment: I noticed from start that this max uint was showing up because a uint was being decremented below 0. What I really did NOT noticed, was that my condition would be always true. (not sure if this makes me less or more dumber :P ). I solved with this: `for (var i:uint = 8; i >= 0, i < uint.MAX_VALUE ; i-- ) `

Comment: @MarceloAssis - It was a good question don't be so harsh on yourself!  I'm glad you solved it.

Comment: I sort of disagree with the assertion that this has nothing to do with the programming language. The designers of AS3 chose to mimic the behavior in C/C++. The behavior is neither inherent or logical. For an interpreted language like AS3, it'd be more consistent for the VM to throw an exception in this case.

Comment: Cleong an unsigned int has nothing to do with a language.